# Count maximum and opened EF connections

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, performance, debugging, entity-framework-4.1

I have ASP.NET MVC app which suffer from performance bottleneck. I would like to profile EF connections and find out maximum allowed EF connections and current opened connections. Any suggestions how to do that?

My Repository code

```
    using EntityFramework.Patterns;


     public class ServiceRepository : IServiceRepository
        {
            private readonly IRepository<User> _userRepository;
            private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;


            public ServiceRepository(DbContext dbContext)
            {
                var dbContextAdapter = new DbContextAdapter(dbContext);
                _unitOfWork  = new UnitOfWork(dbContextAdapter);            
                _userRepository = new Repository<User>(dbContextAdapter);
            }

            public IQueryable<User> GetUsersByProduct(int productId)
            {
                return _userRepository.AsQueryable().Where(p => p.Orders.Any(o => o.ProductId == productId));
            }
//Skip code

        public void Commit()
        {
            _unitOfWork.Commit();
        }

    }
```

Injection with Ninject

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
       var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Entities"].ConnectionString;
       kernel.Bind(typeof(DbContext)).ToMethod(context => new DbContext(connectionString)).InRequestScope();           
       kernel.Bind<IServiceRepository>().To<ServiceRepository>().InRequestScope();
}
```

Comment: Are you disposing your DbContext/ObjectContext objects are using the "using" construct? If not you may be leaking connections. Also, are you sure that this problem is caused by dangling connections? How did you get find this out?

Comment: I am using Ninject to inject DbContext to Repository with scope InRequestScope(). I believe that DbContext should be disposed. I am not sure that my performance issues is related with connections. Just trying to find where it is piece by piece.

Comment: What do you see? What are the symptoms of your performance problems? Have you tried profiling your app?

Answer (score 0):

An EF connection uses an underlying connection type, which may be your issue - your EF context is keeping them open.

Are you going against sql server? 
If so then the issue would likely be your sql connections. Use ANTS profiler to find out where the perf issue is and optimize from there.

You can use the MiniProfiler or glimpse to view your entity framework queries and some execution stats. I would also ensure you are disposing of your context after *every* request and therefore creating a new one per request.